# Process prefix queries in a binary string efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, math, optimization, data-structures

Given an binary string `S` (contains '0' or '1' only), we need to process 2 type of queries as following:

1. `1 K V` : Update the value of `Kth` index in the string with value `V`(can only be 0/1 character).
2. `2 L R` : Print the value of `Fun(L, R)`: for substring `X = S[L: R]` and we take the prefix `Y = S[0: R - L]` and count the num of positions for which `X[i] != Y[j]`, for i = [L, R], j = [0, R - L].

**Constraints :**

```
N (length of S)      <= 10 ^ 5
Q (number of query ) <= 10 ^ 5
```

**Sample test case:**

```
S = "111101"
Query(2 3 5) = 1
```

**Explanation** :

Here, X = '101' and Y = '111', only `X[1] != Y[1]`, rest all bits are positionally same.

**Approach**:

```
public List<Integer> solve(StringBuffer S, int[][] q) {
   int N = S.length();
   int Q = q.length();

   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
      
      if(Q[i][0] == 1) // type-1
         S.setCharAt(Q[i][1], Q[i][2]);

      else if(Q[i][0] == 2) { // type-2

         int L = Q[i][1];
         int R = Q[i][2];
         int count = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < R - L + 1; i++, L++) {
            if(S.charAt(i) != S.charAt(L))
               count += 1;
         }

         result.add(count);
      }
   }


   return result;
}
```

**Time Complexity** : `O(Q * N)`

How can we solve this problem more efficiently, such that the time complexity for each query would be less that `O(N)`.

Comment: Why do you think your time complexity is O(Q * N)? Because it seems you are already there.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes He is not already there - solve is called Q times and will operate on N elements in the worst case each time.

Comment: This problem is very similar to finding the Hamming distance between a string and cyclic rotations of the string. Being able to find those distances in sublinear time (without update queries) seems hard enough; perhaps you want to look into discrete Fourier transforms of the lists of equal-value indices.

Comment: I would personally use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html instead of an array of integers, and see if that was fast enough.  Between being able to `set` a bit, `get` a BitSet for a range, `xor` and `cardinality`, you can push this down to efficient operations on a very compact structure.  It will still scale the same, but with a better constant.

Comment: Does this code work? You change the value of `L` in every iteration; also, you have `L` in the loop's condition.

Comment: What would happen if `X` and `Y` were not the same lengths?

Comment: The notation and description of queries is incorrect and inconsistent. For example, `i = [L, R]` should probably be `i in [L, R+1]`. Also, `S[0: R - L + 1]`, interpreting slice notation as normal, does not have the same length as `S[L : R]`. It seems like the code is correct and the description is wrong, since the code matches the example input and output.

Comment: @Lrrr, Y is prefix string of size ```len(X) = [L - R + 1]```, so you can assume they are always going to be of same lengths.

Comment: @Lrrr, yes this code does work as the logic is correct, but it's not optimized as per the constraints.

Comment: @kcsquared, please don't consider ```[]``` as the python's slice operation, ```S[L:R]``` is purely for the representational purpose, which represents substring of S starting at index ```L``` and ends at index ```R```.

Comment: Regardless of whether the brackets are slices or inclusive or exclusive. The lengths of [L: R] and [0: R - L + 1] are not the same, no matter which interpretations of brackets you’re using, if you’re being consistent.

Comment: @kcsquared Indeed that's a typo in the description, code is ok though. Fixed the description.